# Error in Xamarin sample App

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am just trying run then Xamarin App to how is this really work. I have downloaded the App from here [Sample App](http://xamarin.com/c-sharp-shirt) . I have successfully installed the Xamarin. when I have tried to run the app it says :-

`Error 1 User code size, 430080 bytes, is larger than 65536 and requires aáIndieá(or higher) License. XamarinStore.Droid`

`Error 2 Using type System.Reflection.Assembly requiresáIndieá(or higher) License. XamarinStore.Droid`

any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It's not a Visual Studio licence which it's complaining about - it's a Xamarin licence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's restriction of [Xamarin](https://store.xamarin.com/) free Starter license. You need to have Indie (or Business) license or you can use 30 days [trial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/beginning_a_xamarin_trial/).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove references to Xamarin.Android.Support.* packages

Comment: how to remove it and why ?

Answer (score 0):

It is now free to register for a Xamarin licence, so this should no longer be an issue.